# Using Rhino mocks with Unity application block

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, rhino-mocks

I am trying to mock UnityContainer for writing test harness in an asp.net mvc 2 application.

are there any examples available ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Answer: Don't.  The container should be invisible to your controllers or anything else you need to test.  If it is leaking into your code then you're probably using it incorrectly and should think about redesigning your code.

That said, if you really, really need to then reference the UnityContainerBase abstract class in your code instead of the UnityContainer class itself.  You'll still be able to pass in the normal UnityContainer object when your application is running, but you'll also be able to get RhinoMocks to generate a mock of UnityContainerBase to pass in when you are running unit tests.